# PHP array INSERT into MySQL failing

Tags: php, mysql

Many posts similar to mine,none of them work.

Have an array `$data['date'], $data['name'], $data['value']`.

Trying to insert into MySQL table MyValues (Date, Name, Value)

Have tried 7-8 different methods, none working.
Would like something like

```
for ($a=0;$a<10;$a++) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO MyValues('Date','Index_Name','Index')
       VALUES ($data['date'][$a] ,$data['name'][$a], $data['value'][$a])"
}
```

Have also tried foreach, building a single string to give to MySQL, etc.

Get this error 
Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given on line 45

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, 
[here is a good tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/1723893).

Comment: Is it really legal to have a table named Values?

Comment: @span you can have a table named anything, but it may have to be written as `Values` in queries.

Comment: @span just need the backticks \`Values\`

Comment: a table named `Values` is a really bad idea.

Comment: Please don't call your table `values` and [escape your SQL injections](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You **cannot** insert arbitrary data into your query without escaping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Values` is a reserved word, you can't use it as is for a table name. You must use backticks to enclose it. Similarly, it is not valid to use single quotes to name columns, you need backticks there too.

Try this:

```
$out = Array();
$esc = "mysql_real_escape_string";
foreach($data['date'] as $k=>$v) {
    $out[] = "('".$esc($data['date'][$k])."', '".$esc($data['name'][$k])."', "
       ."'".$esc($data['value'][$k])."')";
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Values` (`Date`, `Index_Name`, `Index`) values ".implode(",",$out));
```

Comment: I think you've just demonstrated why using `mysql_query` is a very bad idea. While clever, this is a giant mess.

Answer (score 3):

columnName shouldn't be wrap with single quotes as they are identifiers not string literals.

```
INSERT INTO `Values` (Date,Index_Name,Index) VALUES (....)
```

one more thing, the only identifier here that needs to be wrap with backtick is the tableName `VALUES` because it is a Reserved Keyword.

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)
- [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Values(Date,Index_Name,Index) VALUES' on line 1

Comment: ^ Issue resolved. Downvote removed.

Comment: @Kolink I overlooked it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this, use `$a++` not `$ee++`

```
    for ($a=0;$a<10;$a++) {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Values` (`Date`,`Index_Name`,`Index`)
   VALUES ('".$data['date'][$a]."' ,'".$data['name'][$a]."', '".$data['value'][$a]."' ")
 }
```

Comment: Close, but *still* wrong...

Answer (score -1):

First of all, just use PDO/mysqli with prepared statements so you wont ever have any issues like this.

This will solve it though (column names with back-ticks instead of single quotes, and escaped data):

```
for ($a=0;$a<10;$a++) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Values` (`Date`,`Index_Name`,`Index`)
       VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($data['date'][$a])."' ,
'".mysql_real_escape_string($data['name'][$a])."', 
'".mysql_real_escape_string($data['value'])[$a]."'");
}
```

And try to avoid reserved names for your columns like `index`and `values`.

Answer (score -1):

First, I believe you want your query values quoted, so the result is 'value' and not just value. Example:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Values(Date,Index_Name,Index) VALUES ('$data['date'][$a]' ,'$data['name'][$a]', '$data['value'][$a]');
```

If you are doing multiple queries, do something like:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO Values(Date,Index_Name,Index) VALUES ";
for {
  // Add to the string here for each insert item
}
mysql_query($q);
```

Additionally, please start phasing out PHP's mysql_* library in favor of mysqli or PDO.

Comment: I just realized you put the table name of Values. Why would you name a table Values? It's a reserved word in MySql to the best of my knowledge. Try changing the name of the table if all else fails.

Comment: Why are you down voting everyone? Sure, we may not hand you code on a silver platter, but please at least indicate WHY we have down votes so we can try to resolve them...

Comment: sorry noob. hitting wrong buttons -> down vote. Not intentional! sorry

Comment: That's fine. Would you mind unvoting us down? Also, if my answer doesnt work, please tell me any errors or problems you have with it.

Answer (score -2):

This works:

```
for ($a=0;$a<10;$a++) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Values('Date','Index_Name','Index')
    VALUES ('".$data['date'][$a]."','".$data['name'][$a]."','".$data['value'][$a]."')"
}
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Values(Date,Index_Name,Index) VALUES' on line 1

Comment: This doesn't even come close to fixing the problem. Why do people always think it's string interpolation that's the issue? It's not.